# Multiple BSOD's even after clean re-install

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod

I have been getting random BSOD's for a year now. Yes I know, why didn't I come here sooner? I can't seem to figure out the Issue. I even did a clean install of windows a few months ago to see if it would stop. It hasn't. I get them randomly during random activities. It can happen while my computer is idling, playing various games, browsing the internet, etc. Anything. I am sure there is some sort of log I need to post but I don't know what or where it is. If so please let me know and I will get it for you. I started writing the codes down over the last week. For the ones I was around for here are the codes in order.

```
System_thread_exception - RTKVHD64.sys
Reference_By_Pointer
KMODE_Exception_not_handled - KS.sys
Driver_IRQL_not_lesser_or_equal - RTWLane.sys
Page_fault_in_nonpaged_area - win32kfull.sys
Kernal_security_check_failure
IRQL_not_lesser_or_equal
Attempted_Execute_of_nonexecutable_memmory
KMODE_Exception_not_handled - dxgkrnl.sys
IRQL_not_lesser_or_equal
system service execptiom - usbaudio.sys
system service execption
KMODE_Exception_not_handled
```

### **UPDATE**

```
OS - Microsoft Windows 10
MOBO - MSI Gaming Z97 GAMING 5 LGA 1150 Intel Z97 HDMI SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.0 ATX Intel Motherboard
CPU - Intel Core i7-4790K Devil's Canyon Quad-Core 4.0 GHz LGA 1150 BX80646I74790K Desktop Processor Intel HD Graphics 4600 
RAM - HyperX FURY 32GB (4 x 8GB) 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 1866 Desktop Memory Model HX318C10FBK2/16 
PSU - EVGA 120-G1-0650-XR 80 PLUS GOLD 650W Fully Modular NVIDIA SLI Ready and Crossfire Support Continuous Power Supply 
Cooler - Cooler Master Hyper 212 EVO - CPU Cooler with 120 mm PWM Fan 
GPU - EVGA GeForce GTX 960 02G-P4-2966-KR 2GB SSC GAMING w/ACX 2.0+, Whisper Silent Cooling Graphics Card 
Case - Rosewill Galaxy-02 - Black Gaming ATX Mid Tower Computer Case 
SSD - SAMSUNG 850 EVO 2.5" 250GB SATA III 3-D Vertical Internal Solid State Drive (SSD) MZ-75E250B/AM 
HDD- WD Blue 1TB Desktop Hard Disk Drive - 7200 RPM SATA 6Gb/s 64MB Cache 3.5 Inch - WD10EZEX - OEM
Monitor - ASUS VS Series VS247H-P Black 23.6" 2ms LED Backlight Widescreen LCD Monitor (Dual)

Peripherals -
Mouse- Logitech G300s
Keyboard: Logitech G105
Headset: Logitech G430
```

Those are my specs. This includes the only USB devices plugged into my computer.

[Dump files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7dPC8OoStEBdUhKS1NMSUI3RjA) are here (click link)

CPU-Z screenshots https://i.imgsafe.org/ef9ca651d4.png

Comment: Well, it's clearly a hardware problem then. When you get a BSOD, it generates the dump files. Could you upload some of the dump files somewhere?

Comment: if multiple reinstalls don't fix it (especially with different install media), then the issue is either bad driver software (check to make sure you are downloading the latest drivers from the manufacturer) or you have a hardware problem. In my experience, when a motherboard dies, it exhibits the kinds of behavior you are describing.

Comment: I agree with others, this is a hardware problem, start troubleshooting.  If you're getting multiple BSODs about varying drivers, services, and files (etc.) a good place to start with is making sure everything inside is clean and staying cool, followed by testing your RAM.  There's lots of documentation and questions about how to do that, here on SU.

Comment: Definitely a hardware issue.  My first hunch is an overheating processor.

Comment: I have the latest drivers. I posted specs above. Everything in this computer is less than 9 months old. I posted a link to google drive with the dump files. Everythings dust free and cooling isnt an issue. Tested RAM and came back good. Thank you guys.

Comment: Just ran another memory test just to be sure. Came back clear.

Comment: if memtest is fine, check that the RAM timings match. to do this run cpu-z, look if the data from memory and SPD tab match

Comment: Posted screentshots of Memory and SPD above. Thank you @magicandre1981

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RAM speed is totally wrong.

[image: https://i.imgsafe.org/ef9ca651d4.png]

You overclcok the RAM and run it with 933MHz while the RAM only supports 888MHz. Go to the BIOS/UEFI and change the RAM speed to 888 MHz.

Comment: Will do thank you. I never set it that way so it must be a weird default or something.

Comment: It was running on auto. It gave me a drop down and the closest selection was 800. Now my DRAM Frequency is showing 400MHz. That cant be right?

Comment: look for a setting called 1866. KHX 1866 10D3 is 1866MHz RAM. But this is OC. 800Mhz shows as DDR3 1600, which should be best

Comment: I can tell you that when you find a wide variety of BSOD codes and drivers identified in the dumps, it's almost always RAM. Other "system-wide" hardware can do it too, but RAM is by far the most common culprit in these cases. And overclocking the RAM is a sure way to get it to produce errors.

Comment: The Specs for my ram sticks say this : 933MHz fCK for 1866Mb/sec/pin
And it is DDR3 1866

Comment: but this is some kind of OC RAM, which doesn't work for all boards. Change the speed to 800 or 666 Mhz. Also update the BIOS/UEFI: https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/Z97-GAMING-5.html#down-bios. The latest versions has stability improvements listed in changelog.

Comment: Will do. I have the latest version. I will update settings. Gonna say this is answered. If I have more problems I will reopen. Thank you Jamie and Magic